# Are laws of refraction incomplete?

Tags: optics, refraction

If you search somewhere for "laws of refraction", this is the most possible results:

> Laws of refraction state that
> (1) the incident ray, the refracted ray and the line of normal lie on the same plane, and (2) the angle of incidence is proportional to the angle of refraction, aka Snell's Law

In a typical high school textbook, an illustration like the following will usually be shown:
[image]

Now my question is, according to the laws, it can also be drawn this way:

[image]

I know this is wrong, but my point is that drawing the rays like this *apparently does not violate laws of refraction*:

- incident ray, refracted ray and normal still lie on the same plane
- angle of incidence and refraction still follow Snell's Law.

So what is the missing piece? Are laws of refraction simply incomplete?

[P.S. I know the proper proof of laws of refraction from general boundary conditions of Maxwell's equation. But this "laws of refraction" quote from my high school textbook does not seem right to me, and this is why I asked]

Comment: Doesn't it depend on the definition of the angle in Snell's Law? (And of course ray optics is severely incomplete, even in the just the classical paradigm.)

Comment: As far as I know, Snell's Law only specifies that the angle refer to the one between the line of normal and the ray itself

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a good question, and reveals that you have read carefully, and thought about the situation.  You provide only a small snippet of text from a book, and and there is no derivation of the law. Now *I* have a question: do introductory books answer *your* question?  I checked three books commonly seen in introductory classes.  Two provide no derivation.  One does provide a derivation.  A careful look at the derivation reveals that the "wrong" wave is incompatible with the derivation, but it's not explicitly stated, and in fact requires some thought to see that it is incompatible.  I suspect that no intro text explicitly answers your question, but in those books that do provide a derivation, your question is not answered explicitly, but an examination of the derivation shows that the "wrong" answer is not a solution.

A simple, but perhaps unsatisfactory, physical answer is to note that the "wrong" solution requires a reflection, but there is no vertical structure that would provide one.